# Can anyone tell me how to disable Delete key in the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Can i disable delete button in soft keyboard in android.Is it possible.If Possible how can i disable the delete button in soft key button in android.

[image]

Comment: what's the delete button? Do you have an EditText?

Comment: Why is this in the user's interests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your `EditText`

```
yourEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:

                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

;)